# Double brace initialization with nested collections

Tags: java, double-brace-initialize

I know I can declare and initialize a `List` using double braces:

```
// (1)
List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<object>(){{
    add("Object1");
    add("Object2");
}};
```

But I want a `List` of `<Map<Object,Object>>`:

```
// (2)
List<Map<Object,Object>> myList = new ArrayList<Map<Object,Object>>();
```

How can I use double brace initialization (see (1)) with nested collections? My goal is to declare and initialize the data structure in a single line.

Also I would like to know if there are certain drawbacks when using double brace initialization I have to be aware of.

Comment: Just use "normal" initialization code; double brace initialization is difficult to read. Code is WORM (Write Once, Read Many). Note: if this is a static list, use a static initializer.

Comment: Why would you want to write code like that? Do you work alone?

Comment: Don't use the "double braces", because each time you do that, you are creating an useless subclass of ArrayList.

Comment: @kolossus: why, can't i add this in my coding standard?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Double Brace initialization in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java)

Answer (score 10):

Avoid double brace initialization as it a) surprises your colleagues and is hard to read, b) harms performance and c) may cause problems with object equality (each object created has a unique class object).

If you're working on a code style guide this kind of trickery belongs in the **don't** section.

If you really want to be able to create lists and maps inline, just go ahead and create a few factory methods. Could look like this:

```
List l = Lists.of(
    Maps.of(new Entry("foo", "bar"), new Entry("bar", "baz")),
    Maps.of(new Entry("baz", "foobar"))
);
```

However, Vangs example shows exactly how the syntax for your example is for double brace initialization.

Comment: Double brace code can also throw up issues in testing. How would you mock xyz if it is statically initialized, for example?

Answer (score 5):

It's not good idea, because it's hard to read, but you can do following:

```
List<Map<Object,Object>> myList = new ArrayList<Map<Object,Object>>() {{
                    add(new HashMap<Object, Object>() {{
                        put(key, obj);
                    }});
                }};
```

Comment: @vang: thanks for your time and answer but in this you didn't initlize the list :(

Comment: What do you mean? Than what new ArrayList<Map<Object,Object>>() is?

Comment: @Vang: i meant that you gave me an idea to put objects in map..it's fine but want to init. my list as well. hope you got it :)

Comment: Vangs example is correct and creates a `List<Map<Object, Object>>` with exactly one map having exactly one entry of `key: object`.

Comment: I'm afraid we don't understand each other) By the way it better to accept @atamanroman answer