# Nested Double Brace Initialization with HashMap and List

Tags: java, android, collections

I'm trying to control some permissions on my App.
Yesterday I learn how to created Double Brace Initialization, It helped a lot. But now I'm trying to use it nested, but I'm getting a

```
')' expected
```

from the IDE (Android Studio)

Here is my code:

```
public static final Map<String, List> ALL_PERMISSIONS = new HashMap<String, List>() {{
    put("Change-maps", new ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(R.id.button_change_view);}};);
    put("Stores-info-view", new ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(R.id.details_fragment);}};);
    put("Competitors-layer", new ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(R.id.switch_concorrentes);}};);
}};
```

am I missing something in it? 
is that a bad approach?

PS: I'm trying this approach because in the future I'll use some keys with more than one View (Integer), and some keys with a list of String.

Comment: it seems like you missed `)` it somewhere... just check braces carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at this code:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put( "string1", "string2" );
```

You can notice that the objects you are passing in parameters are not followed by a `;`.

In your case, the second object you are passing is this one:

```
new ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(R.id.button_change_view);}}
```

So, you don't need the `;` before your `put`'s closing parenthesis, like this :

```
public static final Map<String, List> ALL_PERMISSIONS = new HashMap<String, List>() {{
        put("Change-maps", new ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(R.id.button_change_view);}});
        put("Stores-info-view", new ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(R.id.details_fragment);}});
        put("Competitors-layer", new ArrayList<Integer>(){{add(R.id.switch_concorrentes);}});
}};
```

Answer (score 3):

You should format/indent your code (`Ctrl-Shift-F` by default in Eclipse).

You'd see that your anonymous `ArrayList` class declaration (outside set of curly brackets) cannot be followed by a semi-colon.

Here's a formatted example that will work:

```
public static final Map<String, List> ALL_PERMISSIONS = new HashMap<String, List>() {
    {
        put("Change-maps", new ArrayList<Integer>() {
            {
                add(R.id.button_change_view);
            }
        });
        put("Stores-info-view", new ArrayList<Integer>() {
            {
                add(R.id.details_fragment);
            }
        });
        put("Competitors-layer", new ArrayList<Integer>() {
            {
                add(R.id.switch_concorrentes);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

**Note**

Also mind the raw types or suppress the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I would not encourage the use of double brace initilization. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28410609/1107536) explains, it may

> 1. surprises your colleagues and is hard to read
> 2. harms performance
> 3. may cause problems with object equality (each object created has a
>      unique class object).

I would suggest, if possible, to use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`ImmutableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) and [`ImmutableList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html)

for example:

```
public static final Map<String, List> ALL_PERMISSIONS =  ImmutableMap.<String, List>of(
        "Change-maps", ImmutableList.of(R.id.button_change_view),
        "Stores-info-view", ImmutableList.of(R.id.details_fragment),
        "Competitors-layer", ImmutableList.of(R.id.switch_concorrentes)
);
```

or if you need to add more elements:

```
public static final Map<String, List> ALL_PERMISSIONS =  new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, List>()
        .put("Change-maps", ImmutableList.of(R.id.button_change_view))
        .put("Stores-info-view", ImmutableList.of(R.id.details_fragment))
        .put("Competitors-layer", ImmutableList.of(R.id.switch_concorrentes))
        //(... and so on...
        .build();
```